# (Why) Is Zend\Db\ResultSet a TableGateway Feature?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db, tablegateway

The Zend Framework 2 documentation for the [`Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.db.table-gateway.html#tablegateway-features) says, that:

> The [Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway] constructor can take Features in **3 different forms**: as a single **feature object**, as a **FeatureSet object**, or as an **array of Feature objects**.

And `TableGateway` constructor actually [checks](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/TableGateway/TableGateway.php#L43) the type.

So, the fourth argument of the `TableGateway` constructor needs to be compatible to `Feature\AbstractFeature` or `Feature\FeatureSet` or to be an array of `Feature\AbstractFeature` compatible objects.

In the [model part of the Get Started tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html#using-servicemanager-to-configure-the-table-gateway-and-inject-into-the-albumtable) an object of type `TableGateway` is created and it gets a `Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet` as fourth argument:

```
class Module
{
    // getAutoloaderConfig() and getConfig() methods here

    // Add this method:
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                ...
                'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
                    return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

`ResultSet` is not an `instanceof` `AbstractFeature`. But it works.

How does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$feature` is the **third argument**, see [`TableGateway#31`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/TableGateway/TableGateway.php#L31)

The **fourth parameter** needs to be compatible with the [`ResultSetInterface`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Db/ResultSet/ResultSetInterface.php)

Comment: Oooops... OK, I think I need a break. :) Thank you!